# How to turn a dictionary into list in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm using Flask to grab the input from an HTML form, which returns it as a dictionary object, for example:

```
form = {'Name': 'Eddie', 'Comment': 'Nice location', 'Days Stayed': '7'}
```

Now, I can use `dict.items()` to get the dictionary into a format which I can display in an HTML table (list of tuples):

```
formList = [('Name', Eddie), ('Comment', 'Nice Location'), ('Days Stayed', '7')]
```

This stores nicely into a .csv in the following way:

```
Name,['Eddie']
Comment,['Nice Location']
Days Stayed,['7']
```

However, I'd like my .csv (and therefore HTML Table) to store like this:

```
Eddie, Nice Location, 7
Dave, Good Food, 14
Steve, Room was cosy, 10
```

So I can have my field names at the top and create a nice looking table. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Seems like you only want the values so try using dict.values()

Comment: @Bilkokuya or you could just call `values()` instead of `items()`. But you're not guaranteed to get them in the right order.

Comment: Use a [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're already working with Python's `csv` module, here's a longform way of doing it, if you wanted headers.

This example uses the [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) which is specifically designed to work with dictionaries.

```
import csv

form_data = [
    {'Name': 'Eddie', 'Comment': 'Nice location', 'Days Stayed': '7'},
    {'Name': 'Dave', 'Comment': 'Good Food', 'Days Stayed': '14'},
    {'Name': 'Steve', 'Comment': 'Room was cosy', 'Days Stayed': '10'}
]

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    # this defines the fields you want from dictionaries
    # you pass to the writer, and the order in which they should
    # be emitted in the resulting CSV
    fields = ['Name', 'Comment', 'Days Stayed']
    dw = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames)

    # omit this if you don't want a header written
    dw.writeheader()
    for row in form_data:
        dw.writerow(row)
```

Resulting `output.csv` looks like this:

```
Name,Comment,Days Stayed
Eddie,Nice location,7
Dave,Good Food,14
Steve,Room was cosy,10
```

You can similarly deserialize using the [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class provided by `csv`.

```
import csv

rows = None
with open('output.csv') as csvfile:
    fields = ['Name', 'Comment', 'Days Stayed']
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    rows = [row for row in reader]
```

`rows` will look like this:

```
[{'Comment': 'Nice location', 'Days Stayed': '7', 'Name': 'Eddie'},
 {'Comment': 'Good Food', 'Days Stayed': '14', 'Name': 'Dave'},
 {'Comment': 'Room was cosy', 'Days Stayed': '10', 'Name': 'Steve'}]
```